# asp.net multiple server side forms on a page

Tags: asp.net, html

I have the need to have 2 html forms on one page. One for login details, and one for feedback. Both forms cannot have `runat="server"` attrib.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The article [Form-based Programming in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164151.aspx) may be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Handle one of the forms as a regular HTML form -- don't use runat="server".  Extract the values from any post from the Request.Form collection manually (since there won't be any server-side variables corresponding to the form).

Alternatively, put all the elements in the same form, but use different controls to submit.  Each set of controls (and their submit button) should be in a different validation group to avoid having validation errors due to elements you don't care about.  Handle the form processing in the callback for the submit button.

Also, I would recommend an eventual move to ASP.NET MVC.  MVC is a much better architecture from the perspective of the web.  It more closely aligns with the stateless web model and does not have the limitations imposed in ASP.NET to help it mimic WinForms development.

Answer (score 1):

When using web forms, you should only ever have one form on the page. Probably crap, but such is a web forms world...

wrap one form around the whole page.  Then when a button is clicked (or whatever event you are using) you should be able access the values of all the controls on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as you said, in ASP.NET you can't have more then one form element. but, you can handle more then one action in the same form. Do not use form's action attribute, use asp.net server controls like <asp:Button>, and write your logic into the event of the controls that post back.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET page framework architecture allows single **form** with `runat="server"` attribute. You need not to worry about this thing. Place the controls on to the webform for two different purposes and handle the click events of two asp.net server control `<asp:Button>` separately.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to split them up logically inside the one form. If you use validator and don't want the two "forms" to require the other values filled in, you have a property on the .NET controls called ValidationGroup, that just needs to be the same for all in one "form".

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to make two forms with runat="server" in one page.

Here is a nice solution

[Can I have two separate forms runat="Server" in one page](http://forums.asp.net/p/517576/517779.aspx#517779)

Answer (score 0):

though not a straight forward approach, [you CAN have multiple server side forms on the same page](http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=132&pId=) , but it has its own limitations. [Cost $50](http://www.wilsondotnet.com/WebForm/default.aspx)